# Learning math symbols

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-set-theory, notation, quantifiers

I am taking linear algebra and none of this stuff is expained. I found this helpful link http://www.math.ucla.edu/~pskoufra/M115A-Notation.pdf

but it is missing a lot of what I need to know. Just right now though what does v and ^ mean in the context of linear algebra and set stuff? It is not defined anywhere in my book and it is exceptionally frustrating trying to read this...stuff. Also what does something like upside down A$ x(x \epsilon A _> x \epsilon B)$ mean?

More context

$ x(x \epsilon A _> x \epsilon B) $^ 4 \exists x \in B $ ^ $x $ \not\in A)$

Comment: Type \$\forall\$ to get $\forall$, \$\exists\$ to get $\exists$, \$\in\$ to get $\in$ and \$\not \in\$ to get $\not \in$.

Comment: What book are you using? the ^ is not a universal notation, it is just a marker and is used with different meanings in different places. If you tell which book maybe the meaning can be guessed. The $\forall$ symbol has a universal meaning. You can read it as "for all". So $\forall x ...$, means "for all x ..."

Comment: You might find this helpful: [List of mathematical symbols](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols)

Comment: I am using Kenneth Rosen's Discrete Mathematics and its applications Seventh Edition

Comment: Oh! It is not a book for linear algebra. I see now, why the $\wedge$ appears. I thought your symbol might be a ^ hat on top of some letter, which in linear algebra may be a dual, or coordinate, or many other options.

Comment: I just glanced at the amazon.com preview for [the book](http://www.amazon.com/dp/0072899050) you cited two comments above this one, and the two symbols you asked about (as an example of symbols not defined) are discussed on p. 4 (the connectives *and* and *or* from logic).

Comment: I am an idiot, it is a discrete mathematics course.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Oh wow that was extremely difficult to find, we were assigned chapter 2 to start so I was working back from there with a PDF file.

Comment: Paul, I just looked again at the amazon.com preview and managed to find a list of math symbols near the beginning of the book (it might be inside the front cover of the hard copy; it wasn't in the preview pages I saw yesterday), which says it is continued at the back of the book (which I wasn't able to get a preview of). I would have thought something like this would be worth mentioning in the table of contents, but I didn't see the symbol list mentioned in the table of contents.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Thanks, unfortunately I have the PDF verison of the book and I can't find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes, $\wedge$ is used to mean "and", whereas $\vee$ is used to mean "or." The LaTeX code for these are `\wedge` and `\vee`, respectively.

$\forall$ means "for all". So if you wrote $\forall x \in S$, this means literally "for every element $x$ in the set $S$."

$\exists$ means "there exists". This is commonly used with $\forall$ in mathematics. For instance:

> Let $E$ denote all even positive integers. Then, $\forall x \in E$, $\exists n \ge 1$ such that $2n = x$.

This means that for any element in the set $E$, we can find some number $n$ greater than or equal to 1 that, when multiplied by 2, becomes $x$. In other words, all even numbers are multiples of 2.

This is a trivially easy example, but the compactness of this nomenclature is certainly useful when you start getting into more complicated definitions of ideas.

Comment: I believe it was Brian M. who taught me that \$\land\$ and \$\lor\$ also yield $\land$ and $\lor$ with the advantadge that they are more intuitive.

Comment: I've always used `\vee` because every time I need the symbol, I think to myself "what's that stupid command for the symbol that's like a vee... oh."

Comment: Oh that makes sense in the context I think, why can't they just use && and ||? No confusion there.

Comment: Nice catch. What's your mnemonic for \wedge?

Comment: @PaulthePirate The notation used in logic predates the notation used in computer, which is conditioned by the characters that are easy to type in a keyboard. Mathematicians haven't been pushed enough to roll back their notation to a keyboard friendly one, since we can use LaTeX.

Comment: @GitGud It reminds me of cheese.

Comment: @PaulthePirate `&&` is hard to write by hand. Ampersands are tricky, and can look like an 8 if not done carefully. In general, vertical bars have many meanings in mathematics. $a\ |\ m$ means "a divides m". $\|A\|_2$ means the matrix 2-norm of $A$, and so on.

Answer (score 4):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logic_symbols) has a list of logic symbols. The expression:

> $\forall x ~ [(x \in A \implies x \in B) ~~~\land~~~ (\exists x \in B ~\text{ s.t. }~ x \in A)]$

can be interpreted to mean:

> For all $x$, both of the following claims hold true:
>
> - If $x$ is in $A$, then we also know that $x$ is in $B$.
> - There exists some $x$ in $B$ such that $x$ is also in $A$.